# Accessing depth data from a pointcloud2 message

Tags: c++, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I want to select the depth (*z*) values of a given row from a `sensor_msgs/pointcloud2` message. I have this code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cloud->width; i++)
{
  int index = cloud->row_step*ROW_NUM + cloud->point_step*i + cloud->fields[2].offset;
  memcpy(&depth_data[i], &cloud->data[index], sizeof(float));
}
```

However the code is probably not correct, as the values it gives don't seem to be the real ones. I chose the middle row of the pointcloud (num. 239) and put the sensor in front of the wall, so "the ray of the middle row" should be normal to the wall and so the z value should be the real distance from the wall. The result was: real distance 2m, the *z* value from the message 0.001. When I changed the row number to some other value, the *z* values were even below 0 (which is definitely not correct as I want to get the forward distances). So what am I doing wrong in my code? (I do not want to convert the ros message to a pcl structure.) Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271230/accessing-depth-data-from-a-pointcloud2-message/) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

You code all seems spot on, however you're assumption that depth is the z axis may be incorrect. See [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) for the coordinate conventions used in ROS, the standard convention has X as the forward direction and Z pointing up. Unless your sensor is using an optical frame convention in which case Z does face forwards.

It's probably worth printing out all three dimensions at several positions in the point cloud to find out what's going on with the data.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0